# how to transform JS object recursively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to transform JS object recursively. but I am facing issue .

Problem : if any Object key has 2 property (only two property) label and value.Then its value changes to label only

**Issue** : **Array converted into object**

here is my INPUT object

```
var input = {
        "general_detail_response": {
            "job_order_number": "J13197",
            "job_order_status": {
                "label": "Completed",
                "value": "COMPLETED"
            },
            "job_order_type": null,
        },
        "vehicle_details_response": [{
            "vehicle_number": "ssssadfwdf",
            "vehicle_type": {
                "label": "Standard Trailer",
                "value": "STANDARD_TRAILER"
            },
            "transporter_name": "sdfds",
            "shipping_details_responses": [{
                "shipping_bill_number": "qwer",
                "metrics_break_down": {
                    "nop": 1223,
                },
                "exporter_name": null
            }],
            "container_details_responses": null
        }],
        "ssr_response": [{
            "service_name": "22"
        }]
    };



function tranformFn(obj) {
    let output = {}
    for (var i in obj) {
        let o = obj[i];
        if (o instanceof Object) {
            if (o.label && o.value) output[i] = o.label;
            else output[i] = tranformFn(o);
        } else output[i] = o;
    }
    return output;
} 

console.log(JSON.stringify(tranformFn(input)))
```

**Current OUTPUT :**

```
{
    "general_detail_response": {
        "job_order_number": "J13197",
        "job_order_status": "Completed",
        "job_order_type": null
    },
    "vehicle_details_response": {
        "0": {
            "vehicle_number": "ssssadfwdf",
            "vehicle_type": "Standard Trailer",
            "transporter_name": "sdfds",
            "shipping_details_responses": {
                "0": {
                    "shipping_bill_number": "qwer",
                    "metrics_break_down": {
                        "nop": 1223
                    },
                    "exporter_name": null
                }
            },
            "container_details_responses": null
        }
    },
    "ssr_response": {
        "0": {
            "service_name": "22"
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
{
    "general_detail_response": {
        "job_order_number": "J13197",
        "job_order_status": "Completed",
        "job_order_type": null,
    },
    "vehicle_details_response": [{
        "vehicle_number": "ssssadfwdf",
        "vehicle_type": "Standard Trailer",
        "transporter_name": "sdfds",
        "shipping_details_responses": [{
            "shipping_bill_number": "qwer",
            "metrics_break_down": {
                "nop": 1223,
            },
            "exporter_name": null
        }],
        "container_details_responses": null
    }],
    "ssr_response": [{
        "service_name": "22"
    }]
};
```

see current output **vehicle_details_response** and **ssr_response** key is object expected be array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check for arrays and handle them separately.

```js
let input={general_detail_response:{job_order_number:"J13197",job_order_status:{label:"Completed",value:"COMPLETED"},job_order_type:null},vehicle_details_response:[{vehicle_number:"ssssadfwdf",vehicle_type:{label:"Standard Trailer",value:"STANDARD_TRAILER"},transporter_name:"sdfds",shipping_details_responses:[{shipping_bill_number:"qwer",metrics_break_down:{nop:1223},exporter_name:null}],container_details_responses:null}],ssr_response:[{service_name:"22"}]};
function transformFn(obj) {
    let output = {}
    for (var i in obj) {
        let o = obj[i];
        if (Array.isArray(o)) output[i] = o.map(transformFn);
        else if (o instanceof Object) {
            if (o.label && o.value) output[i] = o.label;
            else output[i] = transformFn(o);
        } else output[i] = o;
    }
    return output;
} 
console.log(JSON.stringify(transformFn(input)))
```